# Can a pin on the arduino be programmed (through code) to output a specific voltage?

Tags: c++, arduino, rc

I am connecting 2 gyroscope motors of an rc helicopter to the output pins on the arduino to make them rotate. Is it possible to slow down the rotation of one motor by programming its pin to decrease its voltage drop? I do not have my arduino yet so I am asking in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm waiting for my arduino to arrive, sorry if my question is misleading

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Comment: This question might be better fitted on the [arduino stackexchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com)....this question really isn't about coding necessarily, which is the purpose of this specific site

Comment: @DarthRubiK: The real arduino forum is http://forum.arduino.cc  ;)

Comment: @datafiddler My link works (at least for me)

Comment: @datafiddler Oh....you posted **that** forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot exactly output an analog voltage on an pin. It's either 0 or 1 logical value. But by using AnalogWrite the pin will issue a PWM (pulse-width modulation, I let you google it for more precise information).
This PWM will work as you expect on your DC motor.

However I don't know how big your motors are but you if consuming more than a few milliamps, you should add a MOS transistor. And even for little motors you should add a flyback diode to your motor to avoid burning your Arduino.